# Leer datos Json de PHP traidos por ajax a Js

Tags: ajax, json

Envío una variable por medio de ajax a un php que me consulta un registro único de acuerdo al id enviado en mencionado ajax, debo traer todos los datos de ese registro, aqui el Js

```
function actualizar_cuenta()
{
  var selector = document.getElementById("select_cuenta_encontrada");
  //capturo el id de la cuenta el cual ya previamente esta configurado en el select_cuenta_encontrada
  var id_cuenta = selector.options[selector.selectedIndex].id;
  //Primero verificamos que si se haya escogido una cuenta y no "- seleccione -" en option del selectedIndex}
  if(id_cuenta=="seleccione")
  {
    alert("debe escoger una cuenta del cliente");
  }
  else
  {
   $.ajax({
   url: "../PHP/consultar_datos_de_cuenta.php",
    type: "POST",
    dataType:'json',
    data:({id_cuenta: id_cuenta}),
    }).done(function(respuesta)
    {
      var nombre=respuesta[1];
      alert(nombre); //aqui pruebo y me imprime "undefined"
     });
  }
}
```

aqui el PHP consultar_datos_de_cuenta.php

```
<?php
include "conectar.php";
$nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
//$sql = "SELECT id,valor_recibido FROM cuentas WHERE nombre_cliente=".$nombre;
$sql = "SELECT id,valor_recibido FROM cuentas WHERE nombre_cliente='$nombre'";

$result = mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);

/*ACA CREO UN ARRAY EL CUAL ME RECOGE LOS RESULTADOS DE LA CONSULTA*/
$array_resultado = mysql_fetch_row($result);

/* CONVIERTO MENCIONADO ARRAY EN FORMATO JSON PARA LUEGO LEERLO EN EL actualizar_cuenta.js*/

echo json_encode($array_resultado);

?>
```

si oprimo F12 en el explorador y voy a Network, php me arroja lo siguiente, por lo cual veo que la consulta se está haciendo bien y se está haciendo el echo que deberia resultar

> [{0: "86", 1: "JAIRO MARTINEZ", 2: "56565", 3: "332", 4: "1", 5: "1", 6: "3614", 7: "6", 8: "5",…}]
>   0
>   :
>   {0: "86", 1: "JAIRO MARTINEZ", 2: "56565", 3: "332", 4: "1", 5: "1", 6: "3614", 7: "6", 8: "5",…}
>   0
>   :
>   "86"
>   1
>   :
>   "JAIRO MARTINEZ"
>   2
>   :
>   "56565"
>   3
>   :
>   "332"
>   4
>   :
>   "1"
>   5
>   :
>   "1"
>   6
>   :
>   "3614"
>   7
>   :
>   "6"
>   8
>   :
>   "5"
>   9
>   :
>   "6345"
>   10
>   :
>   "6"
>   11
>   :
>   "16"
>   12
>   :
>   "64"
>   13
>   :
>   "0"
>   14
>   :
>   "0"
>   15
>   :
>   "0"
>   16
>   :
>   "0"
>   17
>   :
>   "0"
>   18
>   :
>   "0"
>   19
>   :
>   "0"
>   20
>   :
>   "0"
>   21
>   :
>   "0"
>   22
>   :
>   "11"
>   23
>   :
>   "1"
>   24
>   :
>   "65"
>   25
>   :
>   "456"
>   26
>   :
>   "634"
>   27
>   :
>   "612"
>   28
>   :
>   "146"
>   29
>   :
>   "46"
>   30
>   :
>   "0"
>   31
>   :
>   "0"
>   32
>   :
>   "0"
>   33
>   :
>   "0"
>   34
>   :
>   "0"
>   35
>   :
>   "0"
>   36
>   :
>   "0"
>   37
>   :
>   "0"
>   38
>   :
>   "0"
>   39
>   :
>   "0"
>   40
>   :
>   "NO"
>   41
>   :
>   "NO"
>   42
>   :
>   "NO"
>   43
>   :
>   "NO"
>   44
>   :
>   "NO"
>   45
>   :
>   "NO"
>   46
>   :
>   "NO"
>   47
>   :
>   "NO"
>   48
>   :
>   "NO"
>   49
>   :
>   "NO"
>   50
>   :
>   "NO"
>   51
>   :
>   "NO"
>   52
>   :
>   "NO"
>   53
>   :
>   "NO"
>   54
>   :
>   "NO"
>   55
>   :
>   "NO"
>   56
>   :
>   "NO"
>   57
>   :
>   "NO"
>   e_cancela_biometria
>   :
>   "634"
>   e_cancela_boletaf
>   :
>   "65"
>   e_cancela_registro
>   :
>   "456"
>   e_compraventa
>   :
>   "0"
>   e_desembargo
>   :
>   "0"
>   e_deuda_acreedor_hipotecario
>   :
>   "0"
>   e_deuda_acreedor_personal
>   :
>   "0"
>   e_domicilios
>   :
>   "0"
>   e_favor_boletaf
>   :
>   "11"
>   e_favor_registro
>   :
>   "1"
>   e_honorarios
>   :
>   "0"
>   e_impuestos
>   :
>   "612"
>   e_levantamiento_aceptacion
>   :
>   "0"
>   e_otros
>   :
>   "0"
>   e_pazysalvo_areametropolitana
>   :
>   "0"
>   e_pazysalvo_predial
>   :
>   "46"
>   e_pazysalvo_valorizacion
>   :
>   "146"
>   e_remanente
>   :
>   "0"
>   egreso_lazo_oriente
>   :
>   "56565"
>   id
>   :
>   "86"
>   j_cancela_biometria
>   :
>   "NO"
>   j_cancela_boletaf
>   :
>   "NO"
>   j_cancela_registro
>   :
>   "NO"
>   j_compraventa
>   :
>   "NO"
>   j_desembargo
>   :
>   "NO"
>   j_deuda_acreedor_hipotecario
>   :
>   "NO"
>   j_deuda_acreedor_personal
>   :
>   "NO"
>   j_domicilios
>   :
>   "NO"
>   j_favor_boletaf
>   :
>   "NO"
>   j_favor_registro
>   :
>   "NO"
>   j_honorarios
>   :
>   "NO"
>   j_impuestos
>   :
>   "NO"
>   j_levantamiento_aceptacion
>   :
>   "NO"
>   j_otros
>   :
>   "NO"
>   j_pazysalvo_areametropolitana
>   :
>   "NO"
>   j_pazysalvo_predial
>   :
>   "NO"
>   j_pazysalvo_valorizacion
>   :
>   "NO"
>   j_remanente
>   :
>   "NO"
>   nombre_cliente
>   :
>   "JAIRO MARTINEZ"
>   p_cancela_biometria
>   :
>   "5"
>   p_cancela_boletaf
>   :
>   "3614"
>   p_cancela_registro
>   :
>   "6"
>   p_compraventa
>   :
>   "0"
>   p_desembargo
>   :
>   "0"
>   p_deuda_acreedor_hipotecario
>   :
>   "0"
>   p_deuda_acreedor_personal
>   :
>   "0"
>   p_domicilios
>   :
>   "0"
>   p_favor_boletaf
>   :
>   "1"
>   p_favor_registro
>   :
>   "1"
>   p_honorarios
>   :
>   "0"
>   p_impuestos
>   :
>   "6345"
>   p_levantamiento_aceptacion
>   :
>   "0"
>   p_otros
>   :
>   "0"
>   p_pazysalvo_areametropolitana
>   :
>   "64"
>   p_pazysalvo_predial
>   :
>   "16"
>   p_pazysalvo_valorizacion
>   :
>   "6"
>   p_remanente
>   :
>   "0"
>   valor_recibido
>   :
>   "332"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bueno el `undefined` es porque en `var nombre=respuesta[1];` la posicion uno no existe si no la `0`, que es donde esta el primer dato, si quieres obtener el nombre del cliente seria, `var nombre=respuesta[0][1];`

Comment: Gracias muy amable!! una cosita mas a modo de informacion, en total son 58 datos de esa consulta que como puedes ver van del 0 al 57, por que vuelve y se repite esos resultados pero esta vez no con un orden numerico si no con el nombre de la columna en mysql? Gracias!

Comment: Ya es un error en el PHP, no estoy muy seguro pero creo que debes utilizar `mysql_fetch_array` en vez de `mysql_fetch_row`